# Нужна ли запятая перед деепричастием?

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастный-оборот

Держусь на плаву меняя положение на груди и на спине.

Comment: Вы сомневаетесь, деепричастный ли это оборот? Он самый.

Comment: Спасибо!
я даже уже забыла такое название "деепричастный  оборот". За пределами России редко пишешь тексты на русском :)

Comment: Не вполне ясно, что вы хотите сказать. Вы (1) меняете положение тела, чтобы удержаться на плаву, (2) удерживаетесь на плаву и на груди, и на спине, и меняя положение тела (переходя с груди на спину)? Может что-то третье?

Answer (score 2):

Деепричастный оборот – это деепричастие с зависимыми словами.
Как и одиночное деепричастие, обозначает добавочное действие и совершается тем же лицом, предметом или явлением, которое совершает основное действие. Всегда обособляется. Отвечает на вопрос «что делая?» или «что сделав?». Действие обычно относится к подлежащему.

Ваше предложение может иметь такой вид (всё зависит от того, какой смысл Вы в него вкладываете):

**Держусь на плаву, меняя положения "на груди" и "на спине".**

Или:
**Держусь на плаву на груди и на спине, меняя положения.**

Comment: Спасибо, 2 вариант

Comment: Похоже, здесь требуется корректировка:  "...меняя положениЕ" (имеется в виду положение тела, не так ли?)

Comment: Я долго крутила-вертела это предложение. Есть положение "на спине",  есть положение "на груди" — все-таки их два,но одно на другое.

Comment: У меня сейчас нет возможности искать доказательства, но я уверен: меняют положениЕ тела, направлениЕ движения и т.п.

Comment: Здесь "менять" в смысле "изменять", а не в смысле "менять одно на другое"

Answer (score 0):

Задумавшись, как построить фразу так, чтобы она звучала "гладко", приходишь к выводу, что не все так просто. Многое зависит от того, что именно Вы хотите сказать.  Вы (а) меняете положение тела, чтобы удержаться на плаву, или (б) держитесь на плаву и на груди, и на спине, и меняя положение тела (переходя с груди на спину)? Вы говорите о своей способности держаться на плаву в общем или описываете то, что происходит в данное время? Допустим, у нас случай (б). Тогда возможны  такие варианты:

(А) **Держусь на плаву на груди и на спине, переходя из одного положения в другое.**

Этой фразой Вы комментируете то, что происходит с Вами в данное время, или 
описываете Ваше обычное поведение в воде.

(Б) **Держусь на плаву и на груди, и на спине, и меняя положение тела.**

Этой фразой Вы описываете Вашу способность держаться на плаву.

Comment: Спасибо, ближе  к истине вариант "меняете положение тела, чтобы удержаться на плаву", т.е "способности держаться на плаву в общем"
Смысл действия- держаться на воде,  всё равно на спине  или на животе. Главное-держаться и при этом можно менять положение Это будет рекламный плакат для новой учебной программы в школах. Спасибо,  плакат пошёл в работу